# DynamoDB To ElasticSearch Geohash

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-elasticsearch

I followed [this article](https://medium.com/@vladyslavhoncharenko/how-to-index-new-and-existing-amazon-dynamodb-content-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-30c1bbc91365) to index my `DynmoDB` content with amazon `ElasticSearch`. I have a nested field inside each `DynamoDB` row called `location` that contains 5 items: `latitude`, `longitude`, `horizontal accuracy`, `vertical accuracy`, and `altitude`.

When I index my `DynmoDB` content with `ElasticSearch` through [this lambda function code](https://github.com/vladhoncharenko/aws-dynamodb-to-elasticsearch/blob/master/scripts/dynamodb-to-es.py) (referenced in the previous link), each item is labelled type `float` which is correct. However, I want to label `location` as a `geo-point` and utilize `ElasticSearch`'s `geohash` capability so I can perform geospatial queries.

What should I do to convert `location` to `geo-point` and index each row using `geohash`? I'm new to `ElasticSearch` so I'm sure I messed up some terminologies.

Answer (score 0):

What does your ElasticSearch index mapping look like? You should design your index mapping so that ElasticSearch knows that `location` is a `geo-point`. You really shouldn't have to "convert" anything - ElasticSearch should be converting your request to the appropriate field types based on the index definition

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html